# Raphael how to add onclick action that changes colour for the last clicked object

Tags: raphael

Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534776/raphael-how-to-add-onclick-action-that-changes-colour/11884574#11884574), here is what I have done :

```
var current = null;
for (var state in fr) {
    (function (st, state) {
        st[0].state = 0;
        st[0].onmouseover = function() {
            st[0].style.cursor = "pointer";
            current && fr[current].animate({fill: "#EAEAEA", stroke: "#d5d5d5"}, 300);
            st.animate({fill: "#EC5505", stroke: "#EC5505"}, 300);
            st.toFront();
            paper.safari();
            document.getElementById(state).style.display = "block";
            current = state;
        };

        st[0].onmouseout = function () {
            if (this.state == 0)
                st.animate({ fill: "#EAEAEA", stroke: "#D5D5D5" }, 500);
            else
                st.animate({ fill: "#EC5505", stroke: "#EC5505" }, 500);
            st.toFront();
            paper.safari();
        };

        st[0].onclick = function () {
            st.animate({ fill: "#EC5505", stroke: "#EC5505" }, 500);
            st.toFront();
            if (this.state == 0) {                        
                this.state = 1;
            }
            else
                this.state = 0;
            paper.safari();
        };
    })(fr[state], state);
}
```

I have a few problems... When I click on an area then hover out (fill in #EC5505 on hover) this area, the area go back to #EAEAEA for a half second and back to #EC5505... Normally, this should keep the hover color when it's clicked... The second problem is that I want to have only one area selected. So when I click on a second area, the first one has to go back to the initial state.

Could you help me ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Its got something to do with your events ... because the mouseover event fires when you go to click the element ... when you leave the mouseout event fires and hence the animation in click and mouseout both get fired ...

For the second problem you will have to keep a reference of the element that got clicked last ... so that when you click an element you check

```
if(element has already been clicked){
   // go back to original state
}
```

try attatching a boolean to the set[0] ... or 
when set[0] is clicked ....

```
`var clickedElement = set[0]`
```

inside the onclick function

```
if(clickedElement){
// you already have a clicked element so restore its state
}
```